# How to set condition when using filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return all the items which broke a relationship in the following array:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

As you can see each item is linked each other using the property `bound_id`, if a property broke a relation like:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

the following result is returned:

```
[
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }}
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

I'm using the following code:

```js
const input = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];

const output = input.filter(a => a.option.bound_id);

console.log(output);
```

I want to include is to insert only the relationship of the items which are next, an example is better:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

as you can see the item with id `2` broke the relation with id `12` and point to an item with id `3` that doesn't exist in the collection, in this scenario the output should be:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }}
]
```

how can I do this using filter?

Comment: So despite the fact that the item with an `id` of 3 doesn't exist in the collection, you want to keep the item with a `bound_id` of 3 anyway? I don't understand the significance of the `id` properties, if an item is kept regardless (and you're only trying to remove duplicate `bound_id`s past index 0)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, the logic is: remove all the items that following the item that broke the relationship

Comment: Refer to [this](https://alligator.io/js/filter-array-method/). Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: @CertainPerformance the id is unique, there can't be duplicates under any circumstances, so there's no reason to worry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using `.filter`, you might add to a `Set` of the `id`s, and `.filter` by whether the `bound_id` being iterated over is included in the `Set` yet (if not, add it to the set; if so, have the item fail the `.filter` test). Also keep the item if the index is 0, since you always want to keep the first record:

```js
const input = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];
const alreadyHave = new Set();
const filtered = input.filter(({ option }, index) => {
  const { bound_id } = option;
  if (!alreadyHave.has(bound_id) || index === 0) {
    alreadyHave.add(bound_id);
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(filtered);
```

If, per comment, you actually want to always *remove* the first item, then change the condition to `&& index !== 0`:

```js
const input = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];
const alreadyHave = new Set();
const filtered = input.filter(({ option }, index) => {
  const { bound_id } = option;
  if (!alreadyHave.has(bound_id) && index !== 0) {
    alreadyHave.add(bound_id);
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Or, per comment, if the logic for the first item should be the same, remove the `index` condition entirely:

```js
const input = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];
const alreadyHave = new Set();
const filtered = input.filter(({ option }, index) => {
  const { bound_id } = option;
  if (!alreadyHave.has(bound_id)) {
    alreadyHave.add(bound_id);
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: seems to work partially… if there is only one item in the collection, `filtered` will also contains the only item avaialble in `input` but should be empty because no item broke the relationship

Comment: But you said that `I want always keep the first record.`, thus the `index === 0` test?

Comment: yep, I'm sorry I didn't explained well, I mean that this item should not be available in the `filtered` array, so I shuold remove index === 0?

Comment: Wait, do you mean you actually want to always *remove* the first record? But then, why in the last example does the object with `id: "1"` stay?

Comment: I'm explained bad, actually should be removed

Comment: should I remove the or condition for keep the item?

Comment: See edit, if you always want to remove the first item, flip around the condition: `&& index !== 0`

Comment: the first item need to follow the same logic of the others, forget what I said initially

Comment: could you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306294/array-filter-doesnt-respect-condition-properly

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on cross checking:

```js
const input1 = [
    { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }}
];
const input2 = [
    { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
    { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "3" }},
    { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];
const input3 = [
    { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }},
    { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
    { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];
const input4 = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];

var f = (arr) =>  {
    if (arr.length == 1)
        return arr;
    return arr.filter(function (e, i, a) {
        return (!!a[i+1] && e.option.bound_id == a[i+1].id) ||
                (!!a[i-1] && e.id == a[i-1].option.bound_id);
    })
};

console.log(f(input1));
console.log(f(input2));
console.log(f(input3));
console.log(f(input4));
```